# Deploying WAR file in Docker container

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, containers, war

We have made an user management web application in java with tomcat running on 8085 .

The following is my Dockerfile content:

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8085
ADD /userman.war userman.war
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","userman.war"]
```

Please suggest changes .

Comment: Have you started your docker container with `docker run -it --name $container_name -d -h "$host_name" $image_name` what error are you getting ? run `docker logs $container_name`

Comment: It ran successfully ! I used "docker run -it -d -h 172.17.0.1 javay" to run ..but when i open 172.17.0.1:8080/userman on my browser the application doesnt run .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start your docker container with physical host/system ip address and also hit physical host ip address in your browser.
Sample example :

```
docker run -it -d -h $hostname -p 8085:8085 javay
```

Whenever you start your container it will assign ip address from `docker0` interface.It will be different from your actual ip address.by default docker container will start with `docker0` interface ip address like `172.17.0.1`.

Your physical machine/system ip address will be from `eth0` interface with ip range may be like `10.0.0.1` or `192.168.0.1`. So if you want to access your application running inside your container then you have to visit `http://10.0.0.1:8085/userman` or if docker container is running on same physical machine than you can use like `http://localhost:8085/userman`

Hope this will make sense.

Thank you!

Comment: i have used the " $ jar -cvf YOUR_WAR.war * " outside the WEB_INF to build the war file . ? How can i test the war file ?